# How to copy a network in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am not sure on how to copy over a network in Tensorflow 2.0. There are plenty of answers on how to do it in Tensorflow 1.x, but none about 2.0. Both of the networks are made through subclassing the `tf.keras.Model`, so I can't use the `tf.keras.models.clone_model` function.

I have tried different approaches outlined below but none of them seem to work.

```py
network1 = network2
network1.weights = network2.weights

from copy import copy
network1 = copy(network2)
```

Some of these methods will make a reference to the current network but not actually copy it. Would appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: I don't know, so I'm not posting this as an answer, but maybe [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) will help?

Comment: Getting a 'can't pickle _thread.RLock objects' error on that one.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you provide errors or give more information about what happens that *isn't* what you want in your given examples?

Comment: What about using [`model.save()` and `keras.models.load_model()`](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) to save the one you want to copy and then load it into a new object? Seems a little roundabout, but might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that `model_a` and `model_b` are instantiations of the same Keras Model. Then do:

```
for a, b in zip(model_a.variables, model_b.variables):
  a.assign(b)  # copies the variables of model_b into model_a
```